# UnknownHostException on d

Tags: java, rss, feed

I tried running the following example:

http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/customizing-sect-custom-exec.html

The code that fails basically does:

```
String url = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=60202";
URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
return conn.getInputStream();
```

I can access the URL from a browser / feed reader perfectly.
However when running the code in Java, I get an

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: weather.yahooapis.com
```

Any idea, what might be the issue? Could it be that a proxy in our office is blocking the URL, but then would I be able to access it from browser?

Best,
Will

Answer (score 1):

As of Jan 3, 2019 that URL has been discontinued. See this link for more info:

https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Answer (score 0):

The site is reading fine for me... I'm assuming that means somehow you're being blocked by that proxy. Try `System.setProperty("http.agent", "Fake Agent");` to trick the proxy/site into thinking you aren't java (Normally the http.agent is Java/version)

Comment: Set the property now, but I receive the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Have you blocked the Java virtual machine from internet access? The exception you are seeing means that the host cannot be resolved to an IP.

Please check your network security settings or firewall to allow the JVM to connect to your requested site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given Internet permission in Android Manifest?